# excanvas throws me errors in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, excanvas

I am using excanvas.js that is used with flot jquery graphs.
When in FF or chrome the graphs show great.
on IE I get this error:

Unknown runtime error  excanvas.min.js, line 144 character 21

```
 el.getContext = getContext;

                // Remove fallback content. There is no way to hide text nodes so we
                // just remove all childNodes. We could hide all elements and remove
                // text nodes but who really cares about the fallback content.
                el.innerHTML = '';


el in the stack is DispHTMLUnknownElement
```

What can that be?

Thank you?

Comment: Try running with the uncompressed version of the script; it'll be easier to debug if you can read the code and get a useful line number in the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had flot.pie.js which was probably incompatible!